# Calculating a value difference roughly week ago per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I've input dataframe like this:

```
|group |    date   |value|
    A   2020-06-30  5
    A   2020-06-25  3
    A   2020-06-15  8
    A   2020-06-08  1
    B   2020-06-30  0
```

I want output dataframe like this (column `prev_roughly_week_ago` is just a helper column and can be omitted in final df`):

```
|group|    date   | value|  prev_roughly_week_ago   |diff|
    A   2020-06-30  5        3.0                      2.0
    A   2020-06-22  3        NaN                      NaN
    A   2020-06-18  8        1.0                      7.0
    A   2020-06-08  1        NaN                      NaN
    B   2020-06-30  0        NaN                      NaN
```

Basically, within every group (A, B), I want to calculate differences with values that was roughly week ago. By rough I mean 7 days but no more than 10 days (both 7 and 10 should be parameterizable). The problem is that `date` is not "regular".

For example `prev_roughly_week_ago`:

- A 2020-06-30, week ago is 2020-06-23, there is no such date for A but there is 2020-06-22 with value 3
- A 2020-06-22, week ago is 2020-06-15, there is no such date for A and also no 14, 13, 12 so np.nan
- A 2020-06-18, week ago is 2020-06-11, there is no such date for A but 2020-06-08 with 1 is in range
- A 2020-06-08, no previous so NaN
- B 2020-06-30, only one value in group so NaN

Difference (`diff`) is just `value` minus `prev_roughly_week_ago`

Here is an sample code to generate input/output dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 'date': ['2020-06-30', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-30'], 'value':[5,3, 8, 1, 0]})

df['prev_roughly_week_ago'] = [3, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]
df['diff'] = df['value'] - df['prev_roughly_week_ago']
```

How to implement it with pandas in clean-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input dataframe:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #convert to datetime
df = df.sort_values(['group', 'date']).set_index('group') #sort by group and date
df['date_shifted'] = df.groupby(df.index)['date'].shift(1) #get date shifted within groups
df['date_diff'] = (df['date'] - df['date_shifted']).dt.days #calculate difference in days between current and previous dates
df['value_shifted'] = df.groupby(df.index)['value'].shift(1) #get value shifted within groups
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['value']-row['value_shifted'] if 
(row['date_diff'] >=7) & (row['date_diff'] <=10) else np.nan, axis = 1) #calculate value difference if date difference satisfies [7,10] window
```